# How to modify two similar queries to optimize my code

Tags: apex, soql, query, performance

I have two queries that are similar except there's a few differences between them. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize this, by querying this once and still do what I want with my code.

**The Code**

```
List<Task__C> tasksToDelete = [SELECT ID, Case__c FROM Task__C
                              WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT Project_Task__c FROM Time__c 
                              WHERE Project_Task__r.Case__c in :oldCaseIDList) AND Case__c in: oldCaseIDList];
List<Task__c> keepCases = [SELECT ID, Case__c FROM Task__c 
                          WHERE ID IN (SELECT Project_Task__c FROM Time__c 
                          WHERE Project_Task__r.Case__c in :oldCaseIDList)] ; 

for (Task__c: task: keepCases) {
    // do something with the cases associated to the tasks
}
// do something with tasksToDelete
```

Comment: Please don't delete posts the community (in this case, me) have engaged on. You're removing content from this public knowledge base that other users could benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your SOQL usage by one query, at the cost of CPU time and the risk of query row limits. **It's not clear whether or not that constitutes an optimization**. In my opinion, it almost certainly does not. The context - which limits are most at risk when you call this code? how much data volume is present in these objects? - is key when evaluating whether or not to make that change.

In this situation as in most such you can "combine" these queries

```
List<Task__C> tasksToDelete = [SELECT ID, Case__c FROM Task__C
                              WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT Project_Task__c FROM Time__c 
                              WHERE Project_Task__r.Case__c in :oldCaseIDList) AND Case__c in: oldCaseIDList];
List<Task__c> keepCases = [SELECT ID, Case__c FROM Task__c 
                          WHERE ID IN (SELECT Project_Task__c FROM Time__c 
                          WHERE Project_Task__r.Case__c in :oldCaseIDList)] ;
```

by writing a single query whose filters are broad enough to encompass both original queries. Unfortunately, here that becomes

```
List<Task__C> tasks = [SELECT ID, Case__c FROM Task__c];
```

which is rather likely to run you into trouble with other limits.